# Difference word descriptions

Tags: meaning-in-context

Why do we say >we are going to sea< when we board a ship that will travel across an ocean?

Comment: Please explain why you think this is a strange expression.

Comment: Yes, please do provide further explanation. We have to say *something* when we are going to sea, so why not "we are going to sea"? What alternatives are you suggesting? Is your beef with a particular word within the phrase? Please clarify.

Comment: I think he maybe hasn't looked up "sea" in the dictionary as I now have to find that it is a generic term for the salt waters of earth, which include the oceans—as opposed to just things that have "sea" in their names.  I learned something new. ^.^

Answer (score 1):

It is an expression, which means to 'set out on a voyage'

> (the fishermen were unable to go to sea in such storms)

*go to sea* could also mean to become a sailor.

> **[go to sea](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+to+sea) -** to become a sailor. (I went to sea at an early age. When I get older, I'm going to go to sea too).

I think here is a related question on this site: [Going to the seaside and going to the sea](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/136993/going-to-the-seaside-and-going-to-the-sea)

Comment: This is entirely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks. I edited my answer above by adding relevant material.